# ipconfig /release not working, why?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

ipconfig /release is not working, why is that?

here is a sequence where I put my cable in get an IP, try ipconfig /release and it tells me it can't release wireless, but there is no wireless connection. i'm just trying to release the wired one.

unplug cable

```
 C:\>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
```

Fine so I plug my cable in

```
C:\>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

C:\>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.8
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
```

Fine so from above, it clearly has an IP. the above is normal.

```
C:\>ipconfig /release

Windows IP Configuration

No operation can be performed on Wireless Network Connection while it has its me
dia disconnected.

C:\>
```

the following doesn't matter much, but I no doubt meant to also say, that after , doing ipconfig /release,  ipconfig showed the LAN still has an IP.  but I and everybody assumed that from the title- correctly.

so, ipconfig /release didn't work on the LAN.

and for those that don't bother to read the comments, the ultimate answer/reason, was that it was a static ip and that's why ipconfig /release didn't work on the LAN.

Comment: @datatoo yes I do have a cable connected, of course, re-read the question, and ipconfig /release should work

Comment: @datatoo no you've totally misread, I have no wireless 0.0.0.0 you may as well remove your comment it's a complete shambles.

Comment: you are absolutely right, misread it totally

Comment: @KCotreau  I notice your answer has been deleted, or you deleted it. Do you still contend that it released, despite my screenshots which were in comments with your answer, proving that it didn't. Did you delete it because you decided you were wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally without a specific adapter being listed, ipconfig is supposed to work on all the adapters. Obviously yours is not in this case. Try focusing ipconfig on the local area connection adapter instead:

```
ipconfig /release local*
```

Comment: that's better now I get the specific message, "Adapter Local Area Connection is not enabled for Dhcp."  and changing it to DHCP now I can do /release. So, solved. nice one.

Comment: ipconfig /release all

Comment: @Moab an interesting one to know of +1, though that gives a different error in that situation, it says "The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation.", an error msg that is not so specific. but good to know about anyway.

Comment: ipconfig /release *  <-- that covers lan*  gives the same (useful) specific error message.

Comment: When I get that error message, I reboot, if that does not work, uninstall the network device in Device Manager, reboot.

Comment: @Moab interesting.. do you think that's better than a method I heard of in the past, of right clicking the network (interface) connection and going to properties and uninstalling those things like client for microsoft networks, then reinstalling them. I suppose your method is quicker and equivalent so better.

Comment: I don't know it it is better, it is just what I have always done in the situation, old habits die hard. I will experiment with your method next time the problem arises.

Comment: @Moab hey don't call it my method, I prefer yours ;-) it's just something I heard of years ago and looks a bit time consuming and not something i've ever done. I prefer your method to that one.. though that aside. For this particular problem, I found the exact solution - first comment to this answer.

Comment: not directly related to this but there's also the repair option which is a bit like a release and renew.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple, really.  Goto msconfig, and start you services back to default.  Restart computer.  open Command Prompt as Admin.

```
--netstat -ano
```

Put that data in your short term memory bank for a minute

```
--ipconfig /release    
--Ipconfig /renew      
--ipconfig /flushdns

exit
```

Goto network properties and recheck the boxes you may have unchecked prior to knowing what you were doing, maybe.

Comment: not sure why you're talking about bringing up msconfig or the rest, and the reason why wired was not being released was that it was static, as you'd know if you read and understood the comments and answer(s) already posted